# Alias quotation and escapes

Tags: temperature

I try to get a alias like this running:

```
alias temp="vcgencmd measure_temp | sed "s/'/°/g" | sed "s/temp=/Actual CPU temperature /g""
```

I tried a lot to escape the quotes but I didn't got it. Probably I can't see the forest out of trees...

Comment: How on earth do you think this is going to understand your nested quotes? Seems inappropriate use of an alias - write a script.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do here?

Comment: @jwh20: Thats quiet simple, I try to replace the ' sign with an ° Symbol because temperture is measured in this unit. I also would like to replace the "temp=" with a better text which is in my opinion "Actual CPU temperature".  the Idea behind is that I could review in a second ssh session with a simple command just the temp during a CPU and RAM intense task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \ to escape characters.

```
alias temp="vcgencmd measure_temp | sed \"s/'/°/g\" | sed \"s/temp=/Actual CPU temperature /g\""
```

Comment: Thanks @joan, that works pretty well :) I feel a little bit stupid right know because rights know it's quiet simple...

Answer (score 2):

A lot of *sed*-work for a few words... how about this instead?:

```
echo "Actual CPU $(vcgencmd measure_temp)"
```

Instead of an alias, you could also put this in a function:

```
cputemp () { printf '%s' "Actual CPU "; vcgencmd measure_temp; }
```

This function can be declared in the same file as an alias (e.g. `~/.bashrc`). Execute the function same as an alias - just type it at the shell prompt:

```
$ cputemp
Actual CPU temp=53.0'C
```

#### EDIT:

And fwiw, your original incantation works as-is when set up as a function instead of an alias:

```
cputemp2 () { vcgencmd measure_temp | sed "s/'/°/g" | sed "s/temp=/Actual CPU temperature /g"; }
```

But here's a puzzle:

In `~/.bashrc`, define two functions:

```
cputemp () { printf '%s' "Actual CPU "; vcgencmd measure_temp | sed "s/'/°/"; }
cputemp2 () { vcgencmd measure_temp | sed "s/'/°/g" | sed "s/temp=/Actual CPU temperature /g"; }
```

And execute them "back-to-back":

```
cputemp; cputemp2
Actual CPU temp=52.0°C
Actual CPU temperature 54.0°C
```

Wonder why the difference? Is it a ["Heisenberg thing"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))  :P

Comment: I tried this as well but the output wasn't formated as I would like to have it. But thanks for your input. btw is it possible to edfine an function in the .bashrc_aliases as well?

Comment: @Marcusg562: [How would you like it formatted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character) [How functions work](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php), [Where are functions saved?](https://www.howtogeek.com/439736/how-to-create-aliases-and-shell-functions-on-linux/). Point being that there are many ways to reformat strings. Was your objective only to replace the `'` with `°` ??

Comment: @Marcusg562: I've made an edit that you may find interesting :)